# Diode circuit using real model

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes

What will be graph b/w Vo and Vi for 0[image]

Comment: Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: Ya I solved it by considering both diode in open mode and proceeded.but that looks biased to me.if we start by considering both in off mode then also everything satisfies. So ,I want a clear method. @Eugene Sh.

Comment: That's a correct way to solve diode circuits. You assume a state and then, if come to a contradiction, you assume another one. For completeness you might want to try to assume a different state and see the contradiction.

Comment: But in later case when considering both diodes off Vo will always be 0.i am not coming to a contradiction.

Comment: You actually have four possible situations, not just two. You may have to consider when one diode is forward biased and the other is reverse biased.

Comment: Ya that's right but if I assume one of the situations and everything goes well.then why I would look into other 3.

Comment: @RohitKumarr You have a range of voltages here to consider. These might  (and will) lead to different configurations. Anyway, you should think of the conditions which are "switching" these configurations and calculate between these.

Answer (score 1):

There are three, not four, circumstances to worry about. Assuming that both diodes are ON, you have the left-side case below. It should also be absolutely clear to you ***why*** the middle case loses the particular branch of the left-side case that it does lose. And finally, the right-side case should be similarly obvious.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXrzBC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Clearly, the left-side case only works if you find the circumstance for \$V_I\$ that achieves the indicated \$V_X\ge +2.1\:\text{V}\$.

The same will be true for the middle case, only now you need to find the circumstance for \$V_I\$ that achieves the indicated \$+600\:\text{mV}\le V_X\lt +2.1\:\text{V}\$.

The right-side is too obvious to bother saying much about.

You should also find that these three models are consistent with each other (you should find that the results make sense to you.)

At this point you may be able to recast your original schematic now that you've worked out when current is flowing in each branch to work out \$V_\text{O}\$ on your own.

Comment: @RohitKumarr I combined your 2nd order model into the schematic in a way I hope you followed okay.

Comment: If you look at the problem, the output is actually a voltage divider of the diode Vr and the 50 Ohm output. Both the left and middle solutions are incorrect.

Comment: @JackCreasey Hmm. Now that you've got my attention it still looks to me as I wrote. But I was looking only for an equivalent to help understand when the diodes were ON and OFF. I was not looking to answer the question about \$V_\text{O}\$, though. I had hoped the OP would work that out.

Comment: @jonk I get concerned when folks talk about diodes as being ON or OFF. They are either conducting (forward bias) or not (reverse bias leakage). I think it's bad to have newcomers talk about ON and OFF states.

Comment: @JackCreasey I suppose. But the OP was quite clear about the 0.6 V + 10 Ohm model. And that doesn't make room for a more realistic model to be applied. Given that simplified OP model, they are either ON or OFF. Unless you have another way of using that model?

Comment: @jonk Even with the simplified model, the diode does not have ON and OFF states, it's ether conducting or not, and the conducting (state if you want to use the term) is an infinite range of forward current values.

Comment: @JackCreasey I only just noticed your answer, just now. (My fault.) I'll read it before commenting again. Sorry about not noticing. Just remember that I was NOT dealing with \$V_\text{O}\$ in my comment.

Comment: @JackCreasey Okay. Before I go further, did you notice on my left and middle diagrams that the bottom node voltage is NOT zero? (My diagrams, by the way, appear to be exactly supported by my running of Spice, just now. That's way I'm asking. But it may be that I didn't add enough description.)

Comment: @JackCreasey Spice tells me:
$$\begin{align*}
0\:\text{V}\le V_\text{I}\lt 600\:\text{mV} \quad\quad&I_{D_1}=0\:\text{mA}, I_{D_2}=0\:\text{mA}\\\\
600\:\text{mV}\le V_\text{I}\lt 2.6\:\text{V} \quad\quad&I_{D_1}=0\:\text{...}\: 25\:\text{mA}, I_{D_2}=0\:\text{mA}\\\\
2.6\:\text{V}\le V_\text{I}\lt 5.0\:\text{V} \quad\quad&I_{D_1}=25\:\text{mA}\:\text{...}\: 37\:\text{mA}, I_{D_2}=0\:\text{...}\: 72\:\text{mA}
\end{align*}$$ Just as my models above would ***exactly*** predict. It appears Spice produces the same results. I may still be mistaken. But I'm not seeing it. Could be me.

Comment: @jonk I only said that you didn't describe Vo, which didn't help the OP. You do appear to have a mistake in the comment above though …..0, 0.6, 2.1 appear to be the intermediate points ….where did you come up with 2.6V?

Comment: @JackCreasey I'd be happy to point out how. But do you want a little more time on your own? Or should I just write out the equation solution?

Comment: No....I get it. My bad

Answer (score 0):

We can redraw the schematic given and from inspection build an answer to the values for Vo and Vin. Deciding the internal node (Node_A and Node_B) voltage is a simple inspection task given the diode Vf is 0.6V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3ZXNm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The table we want to build (with known and unknown elements) so the solution can be graphed is:

\begin{array} {|r|r|r|r|}
\hline
 Vin &Vo &Node_A &Node_B\\
\hline
0 &0 &0 &1.5\\
\hline
0.6 &0 &0.6 &1.5\\
\hline
x_1 &0 &2.1 &1.5\\
\hline
5 &x_2 &x_3 &x_4\\
\hline
\end{array}

The OP should be able to make an attempt at the unknown elements in the table. The 5V line is the most challenging since both diodes are conducting with two separate current paths.

There is enough detail in the schematic to run a DC simulation which should help with the graphing.
the simulation return this result, though the diode is 'real' in the sense that it is a 1N4148 in this simulation.

[image]